# I would like to ask why is 0 part of the argument?

Tags: javascript, function, sum, reduce, rest-parameters

I get the entire logic of the reduce method, and rest parameter, however I really don't get the importance of 0. Thank you very much in advance!

```
const sum = (...args) => {
   return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

Comment: You need that, if you do not want to take the first element as initial previous, or the array does not have any elements. See [how_reduce_works_without_an_initial_value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#how_reduce_works_without_an_initial_value) and the following.

Comment: If you want information on a function, you can always just search [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for it. See [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: 0 is the initial value, this specific reduce is equivalent to `0 + args[0] + args[1] + ... + args[args.length - 1]`, you need the 0 to start the sum. For a product you'd use 1 instead for example.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now I get it!

Comment: When there is no initial value and the array is empty, the browser will show an error, right? Is that the main reason why we state the initial value in the function?

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript is a dynamically typed / untyped / uni-typed programming language (depending on whom you ask). However, it still makes sense to look at the types of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) here.

I am going to use TypeScript syntax, in fact, I am going to use [the definition from the TypeScript library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cec2fda9a53620dc545a2c4d7b0156446ab145b4/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1195), but the actual syntax doesn't really matter:

```typescript
reduce<U>(
    callbackfn: (
        previousValue: U,
        currentValue: T,
        currentIndex: number,
        array: readonly T[]
    ) => U,
    initialValue: U
): U;
```

The fact that the original array and the current index are passed into the callback function is an ECMAScript oddity that is not really necessary to understand how `reduce` works, so let's get rid of those:

```typescript
reduce<U>(
    callbackfn: (
        previousValue: U,
        currentValue: T,
    ) => U,
    initialValue: U
): U;
```

Note also that we have *two* different type parameters here:

- `T` is the *element type* of the `Array<T>`.
- `U` is the *result type* of `reduce`.

So, `reduce` is a function which takes three arguments:

- The invisible `this`, which is the `Array<T>` it iterates over.
- A *function* which combines a `U` and a `T` and produces a new `U`.
- An initial value of type `U`.

*Conceptually*, what `reduce` does is that it "reduces" a *collection* of values down to a *single* value. It is important to understand that this single result value can have an *arbitrary type*. It does *not* have to be the same type as the element type of the `Array`.

`reduce` does this using the reduction function that is passed to it.

So, conceptually what `reduce` returns is

```ecmascript
callbackfn(
    callbackfn(
        callbackfn(
            callbackfn(
                callbackfn(
                    callbackfn(
                        callbackfn(
                            callbackfn(
                                initialValue,
                                this[0]
                            ),
                            this[1]
                        ),
                        this[2]
                    ),
                    this[3]
                ),
                this[4]
            ),
            this[5]
        ),
        this[6]
    ),
    this[7]
)
// and so on …
```

Or, if we write the callback function as a binary operator `ω`:

```ecmascript
initialValue ω this[0] ω this[1] ω this[2] ω this[3] ω …
```

Note that the callback function must be left-associative, i.e. equivalent to

```ecmascript
(((((initialValue ω this[0]) ω this[1]) ω this[2]) ω this[3]) ω …)
```

Many collections libraries, and ECMAScript is no exception, also provide a version of `reduce` that does not have an initial value. In many libraries, this version has a different name (for example, in Scala, the version with initial value is called `foldLeft`, the version without is called `reduceLeft`, in Haskell, the version with initial value is called `foldl`, the version without is called `foldl1`). In ECMAScript, this is instead handled via "overloading", i.e. you can simply leave out the `initialValue` argument.

If the initial value is left out, we instead start off with the first element of the collection, i.e.

```ecmascript
callbackfn(
    callbackfn(
        callbackfn(
            callbackfn(
                callbackfn(
                    callbackfn(
                        callbackfn(
                            this[0],
                            this[1]
                        ),
                        this[2]
                    ),
                    this[3]
                ),
                this[4]
            ),
            this[5]
        ),
        this[6]
    ),
    this[7]
)
// and so on …
```

or written as an operator

```ecmascript
this[0] ω this[1] ω this[2] ω this[3] ω …
```

This has an important consequence, though! Our operator / callback function now needs to take two `T`s and return a `T`, there is no longer a way to have a result type that is different from the element type.

And it has another important consequence: `reduce` no longer works with an empty collection.

So, these would be the two reasons why you would need to supply an initial value:

- You want to transform the type.
- You want the `reduce` to work with an empty collection.

In this particular case, the first reason does not apply: the function is clearly meant to reduce an `Array<number>` to `number`. But the second reason is relevant: you don't want to force clients of the function to have to check whether or not the collection is empty. A client should be able to call

```ecmascript
sum(...someArray)
```

and not worry whether `someArray` is empty or not.

The ability to change the type to an arbitrary type is important for the *universality* of `reduce`. It turns out that `reduce` is a powerful function: it can do *everything* you could do by iterating over a collection. In other words: you could remove *every method* of `Array.prototype` except `reduce`, and also remove `for … of` and `for … in` from ECMAScript, and you could still do everything you could possibly do by iterating over a collection. (Well, you'd need a way to add something to an array, I guess, so let's keep `push` as well.)

Here is just an example of implementing `Array.prototype.map` using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```ecmascript
Array.prototype.map = function map(callbackFn) {
    return this.reduce(
        (previousValue, currentValue) =>
            previousValue.push(callbackFn(currentValue)),
        []
    );
}
```

Here you see that the fact that we can change the type is important, because we start with an `Array<T>`, but we don't want a `T` as a result, we want an `Array<U>`. This also shows that the statement "`reduce` reduces the collection down to a single value" does *not* mean that the result has to be a simple value. The result value can be as complex as you like … in this case, another array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth explanation! Thank you!!